# Debug ItemAdding and ItemUpdating Remove Event Receiver

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, remote-event-receiver, debugging

I have been working on couple of remote event receivers inside our SharePoint online sites.

I followed the step mentioned in these links:

1. [Working with Remote Event Receivers in a Provider Hosted App](https://collab365.community/working-with-remote-event-reciver-in-provider-hosted-app/)
2. [How to Implement Remote Event Receiver in SharePoint Online](https://www.tatvasoft.com.au/blog/how-to-implement-remote-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-online/)

But I am not sure how I can debug these remote event receivers, even the above 2 links did not mention how we can debug RER?

I remember that I used to debug a remote event receivers using Azure Service Bus, but it seems this approach was deprecated by Microsoft.

So can anyone advice, how can I Debug our `ItemAdding` and `ItemUpdating` Remove Event Receivers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **debugging your remote event receiver locally** as given in the below article:

[Remote Event Receivers – you’re all doing it wrong](https://derekgusoff.wordpress.com/2017/11/08/remote-event-receivers-youre-all-doing-it-wrong/).

In order to use this you will need the following things.

1. [Node.JS](https://nodejs.org/en/) and [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).
2. Then Start `ngrok` service and create a RER which points to your `ngrok` service, instead of real URL.
3. Then test your RER locally in Visual Studio.

**Update**:

As per the comments by owner of above article, [Derek Gusoff](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/8056/derek-gusoff):

1. `ItemAdding` and `ItemUpdating` are sychnronous events instead of async.
2. So for such events you just have to implement `ProcessEvent` method instead on `ProcessOneWayEvent` method.

Comment: the approach mentioned in this link https://derekgusoff.wordpress.com/2017/11/08/remote-event-receivers-youre-all-doing-it-wrong/ does not support ItemAdding and ItemUpdating RER....

Comment: Are you getting any error while using it or what??

Comment: the approach mentioned in the link will not support ItemAdding and ItemUpdating events it only support ItemAdded and ItemUpdated.. the author of this link mentioned this to me in old post..

Comment: Hey, I wrote that article - you can totally use it for ItemAdding and ItemUpdating. Those are just sychnronous instead of async, that's all. What specific problem are you having with that?

Comment: Regrardless, ngrok is totally the way to go. Have an upvote Ganesh!

Comment: Thank you @DerekGusoff.  SharePoint TestDev, Can you please try it and let us know what problems you are facing?

Comment: @DerekGusoff i remember we had a previous discussion and you mentioned that using this approach does not support sync actions.. if it support sync actions then this will be much easier to create compared to creating  RER per MS documentations...

Comment: I've used that pattern for an ItemDeleting a couple times. Works fine. You just have to implement ProcesEvent instead on ProcessOneWay event. Good luck!

Comment: @DerekGusoff you are correct i were able to use itemadding without any issues. sorry for the inconsistency that have been raised from my side.

Comment: @DerekGusoff i submitted two issues i am facing inside the article comment section  https://derekgusoff.wordpress.com/2017/11/08/remote-event-receivers-youre-all-doing-it-wrong/, can you please check them. thanks

Comment: @GaneshSanap seems the approach mentioned in the link you provide will not work if we chose AppOnly permission .i wrote another question regarding the issues i faced. @ https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/274304/unable-to-run-a-remote-event-receiver-using-app-only-authentication-error-acce